# on() method doesn't work on dynamically generated HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically adding a table row (`tr`) to my table and these `tr` tags contain some links.

I have a jQuery script which is invoked when the links inside the `tr` are clicked.
The script is not working for these links. It works when I reload the page and the `tr` is populated from the server side.

How can I overcome this problem?

```
$(".comment-like").on('click',function() {
    var spanEle = $(this).closest('li').find('.comment-like-count');
    if (spanEle.length) {
        var newCount = parseInt(spanEle.text(),10);
        spanEle.text(newCount + 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: The initial selector for `on` must exist at the time of binding.

Comment: If you searched your question on `stackoverflow`, you would find like 50 posts...

Comment: @Brad : Well i am like everyone...so i think i am the 51st guy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [delegate the listener to a parent](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) like the table not the links themselves
since they come and go dynamically
Try this:

```
$('your table selector').on('click','.comment-like', function () {
    var spanEle = $(this).closest('li').find('.comment-like-count');
    if (spanEle.length) {
        var newCount = parseInt(spanEle.text(), 10);
        spanEle.text(newCount + 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a parent selector that exists on page load. If you don't have one, use `$('body')`

```
$('.elem-existing-on-pageload').on('click', '.comment-like', function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to attach the event handler for those new Elements after adding them.

Comment: It's fine to use on, he just has to select an element existing on pageload.